# Получить значение по Binding от объекта в коде

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть `DataGrid`, у него есть колонка `DataGridTextColumn`, у колонки установлен `Binding`, я его получаю в коде:

```
for (int j = 0; j < grid.Columns.Count; ++j)
{
  if (grid.Columns[j] is DataGridTextColumn)
  {
    DataGridTextColumn dgtc = (DataGridTextColumn)grid.Columns[j];
    Binding binding = dgtc.Binding as System.Windows.Data.Binding;
    //Далее код 
  }
}
```

теперь как мне получить гипотетическое значение по этому `Binding`, если у меня будет источник свой? Поясню, в строчках `Grid` есть значения, значения ячеек выводятся в зависимости от `Binding`, как мне узнать что выведется в ячейке если элемент коллекции будет какой-либо другой, именно узнать, на форму выводить значения не надо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все достаточно непросто.

Использовал статьи:

[Get result of a Binding in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886221/get-result-of-a-binding-in-code/3886477#3886477),

[Binding does not have a Clone method, whats an effective way to copy it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911532/binding-does-not-have-a-clone-method-whats-an-effective-way-to-copy-it)

1.Создаем метод клонирование `Binding`, дабы не запороть основной(взятый) `Binding`.

```
public static BindingBase CloneBinding(BindingBase bindingBase, object source)
  {
    var binding = bindingBase as Binding;
    if (binding != null)
    {
      var result = new Binding
      {
        Source = source,
        AsyncState = binding.AsyncState,
        BindingGroupName = binding.BindingGroupName,
        BindsDirectlyToSource = binding.BindsDirectlyToSource,
        Converter = binding.Converter,
        ConverterCulture = binding.ConverterCulture,
        ConverterParameter = binding.ConverterParameter,
        //ElementName = binding.ElementName,
        FallbackValue = binding.FallbackValue,
        IsAsync = binding.IsAsync,
        Mode = binding.Mode,
        NotifyOnSourceUpdated = binding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated,
        NotifyOnTargetUpdated = binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated,
        NotifyOnValidationError = binding.NotifyOnValidationError,
        Path = binding.Path,
        //RelativeSource = binding.RelativeSource,
        StringFormat = binding.StringFormat,
        TargetNullValue = binding.TargetNullValue,
        UpdateSourceExceptionFilter = binding.UpdateSourceExceptionFilter,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = binding.UpdateSourceTrigger,
        ValidatesOnDataErrors = binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors,
        ValidatesOnExceptions = binding.ValidatesOnExceptions,
        XPath = binding.XPath,
      };
      foreach (var validationRule in binding.ValidationRules)
      {
        result.ValidationRules.Add(validationRule);
      }
      return result;
    }
    var multiBinding = bindingBase as MultiBinding;
    if (multiBinding != null)
    {
      var result = new MultiBinding
      {
        BindingGroupName = multiBinding.BindingGroupName,
        Converter = multiBinding.Converter,
        ConverterCulture = multiBinding.ConverterCulture,
        ConverterParameter = multiBinding.ConverterParameter,
        FallbackValue = multiBinding.FallbackValue,
        Mode = multiBinding.Mode,
        NotifyOnSourceUpdated = multiBinding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated,
        NotifyOnTargetUpdated = multiBinding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated,
        NotifyOnValidationError = multiBinding.NotifyOnValidationError,
        StringFormat = multiBinding.StringFormat,
        TargetNullValue = multiBinding.TargetNullValue,
        UpdateSourceExceptionFilter = multiBinding.UpdateSourceExceptionFilter,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = multiBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger,
        ValidatesOnDataErrors = multiBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors,
        ValidatesOnExceptions = multiBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors,
      };
      foreach (var validationRule in multiBinding.ValidationRules)
      {
        result.ValidationRules.Add(validationRule);
      }
      foreach (var childBinding in multiBinding.Bindings)
      {
        result.Bindings.Add(CloneBinding(childBinding, source));
      }
      return result;
    }
    var priorityBinding = bindingBase as PriorityBinding;
    if (priorityBinding != null)
    {
      var result = new PriorityBinding
      {
        BindingGroupName = priorityBinding.BindingGroupName,
        FallbackValue = priorityBinding.FallbackValue,
        StringFormat = priorityBinding.StringFormat,
        TargetNullValue = priorityBinding.TargetNullValue,
      };
      foreach (var childBinding in priorityBinding.Bindings)
      {
        result.Bindings.Add(CloneBinding(childBinding, source));
      }
      return result;
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException("Failed to clone binding");
  }
```

2.Далее создаем proxy объект, который будет выполнять функцию перевода `Binding` и объекта ресурса в значение по `Binding`

```
class DummyDO : DependencyObject
{
  public object Value
  {
    get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(DummyDO), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

3.И функцию перевода Объект+`Binding`=значение

```
public static object EvalBinding(BindingBase b)
{
  DummyDO d = new DummyDO();
  BindingOperations.SetBinding(d, DummyDO.ValueProperty, b);
  return d.Value;
}
```

4.Функция возвращаемая все дочерние элементы заданного типа

```
public static List<T> GetVisualChilds<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
  List<T> childs = new List<T>();
  if (parent != null)
  {
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
      DependencyObject v = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
      if (v is T)
        childs.Add(v as T);
      childs.AddRange(GetVisualChilds<T>(v));
    }
  }
  return childs;
}
```

далее начинается свистопляска с типами колонок. Их у нас 3 вида

1-DataGridBoundColumn и наследуемые от него

2-DataGridComboBoxColumn

3-DataGridTemplateColumn

PS: `ic` - список объектов, по которым мы вычисляем значения через `Binding`

```
for (int i = 0; i < ic.Count; ++i)
for (int j = 0; j < grid.Columns.Count; ++j)
{
  object resultValue = null;
  if (grid.Columns[j] is DataGridBoundColumn)
  {
    DataGridBoundColumn dgbc = (DataGridBoundColumn)grid.Columns[j];
    BindingBase columnBinding = dgbc.Binding as BindingBase;
    BindingBase binding = CloneBinding(columnBinding, ic[i]);
    resultValue = EvalBinding(binding);
  }
  if (grid.Columns[j] is DataGridComboBoxColumn)
  {
    DataGridComboBoxColumn dgcbc = (DataGridComboBoxColumn)grid.Columns[j];
    BindingBase binding = new Binding(dgcbc.DisplayMemberPath) { Source = ic[i] };
    resultValue = EvalBinding(binding);
  }
  if (grid.Columns[j] is DataGridTemplateColumn)
  {
    DataGridTemplateColumn dgtc = (DataGridTemplateColumn)grid.Columns[j];
    DataTemplate dt = dgtc.CellTemplate;
    ContentPresenter control = new ContentPresenter();
    control.Content = ic[i];
    control.DataContext = ic[i];
    control.ContentTemplate = dt;
    control.Initialized += delegate (object c, EventArgs ea)
    {
      FrameworkElement fwe = c as FrameworkElement;
      fwe.ApplyTemplate();
    };
    control.BeginInit();
    control.EndInit();
    List<FrameworkElement> elems = GetVisualChilds<FrameworkElement>(control);
    resultValue = string.Join(" ", elems.Select(x => x is TextBlock ? ((TextBlock)x).Text : x is TextBox ? ((TextBox)x).Text : null).Where(x => x is string));
  }
  //В resultValue будет значение равное значению в ячейке DataGrid.
}
```

К сожалению осталось несколько вариантов:

1. когда в `DataGridTemplateColumn` используется `ItemsControl` со своим `ItemTemplate`. в этом случае список значений `ItemsControl` мы не получим.
2. Если в `Binding` участвуют `ElementName` или `RelativeSource`

Если есть какие-либо соображения по этому поводу просьба откликнуться.

Comment: Извините, но мне здесь трудно что-либо добавить. С конвертером сам работал, потому и посоветовал вам, а с этим вот... нет. А оно, правда, очень надо? В VS2015 есть же визуальные инструменты дебагинга для WPF, с помощью их можно подглядеть, то что вам надо. Была еще какая-то программулина  с ее помощью можно было подглядеть весь visual tree, свойства контролов и т.п., название ее только вот запамятовал.

Comment: У меня есть DataGrid, мне нужно экспортировать данные из него, допустим, в html. для этого мне нужно получить все текстовые значения по Binding колонкам, однако, если ячейка не визуальна (ниже или выше отображаемой информации) контролов из неё не получить. Вот и приходится с помощью лома и такой-то матери из объекта (DataContext) строки и биндинга получать значения отображаемой информации в ячейке.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, у вас же есть источник данных для этого вашего DataGrid, почему нельзя в коде работать напрямую с этим источником? Почему его сначала нужно отобразить, а потом мучиться с отображенной информацией, переводить ее так сказать в удобоваримый формат?

Comment: @Bulson да потому что нет данных в ячейке, если она не визуальна в данный момент, данные появляются при инициализации контрола, т.е. при его первом появлении. Попробуйте сами и поймёте.

Comment: "...данные появляются при инициализации контрола, т.е. при его первом появлении", но ведь контрол же привязан к какой-то коллекции или датасету и отображает данные оттуда?!

Comment: Да, после его появления, однако если он ниже или выше отображаемой информации, то в ячейке ничего нет, я же написал. Ячейка формируется только после того как должна быть отображена.

Comment: Извините, но мы ходим с вами по кругу. Мне добавить с сказаному больше нечего.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите просто узнать значение, то на мой взгляд, проще всего прицепить конвертер.

```
<converter:DoNothingConverter x:Key="localDoNothingConverter"></converter:DoNothingConverter>
```

в привязке укажите:
    `Converter={StaticResource localDoNothingConverter}}"`

```
 public class DoNothingConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(value.ToString()); //ну или еще чего здесь сами придумейте
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да вот с конвертером то просто. А мне надо в более широком спектре